# Using Akka in separate library

Tags: scala, akka

Maybe it is a stupid question but if I develop library which will use akka features should I create ActorSystem in my library or user will pass it through parameter? What is the best practice?

Comment: Why don't you implement both and let the user choose ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend passing it as implicit parameter, that way the library user can tune the actor system and have total control other the creation of it.

He can for example choose to share a common actor system with other component of the application.

If you are creating a complete framework you can provide a default one which can be easily imported (like Play! is doing).

Comment: Ok. I understand you but what should I if user use my library inside his own actor and would like to pass ActorContext. I try to use ActorRefFactory as implicit parameter but it does not help me.

Comment: I think that the the solution is similar to how ActorDSL works. Thanks!